# Increment float number on phone state idle

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to increment a float number once the Phone State is IDLE. Then save the float number in shared preferences and expose it in the main activity.

Currently what i did was use intent to take in the number on phone state and send to the main activity and on the main activity i saved it. But the phone crashes once i test it. Below is my current code for the **Incoming Call:**

```
public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private View view;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Receiver start");
            Intent intentBundle = new Intent();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putFloat("value", 0.5f);

            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                bundle.putFloat("value", 0.5f);
                intentBundle.putExtras(bundle);
                Toast toast = new Toast(context);
                CharSequence text = "O.5 Added";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast testtoast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                testtoast.show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code i have in my **main activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private float minteger = 0.5f;
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private View view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.appname.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putFloat("value", minteger).apply();

        Float value = sharedPreferences.getFloat("value", 0.0f);

        TextView textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberValue);
        textv.setText(String.valueOf(value));

        context = getApplicationContext();
        activity = this;
        Button check_permission = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check_permission);
        Button request_permission = (Button) findViewById(R.id.request_permission);
        check_permission.setOnClickListener(this);
        request_permission.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        view = v;

        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.check_permission:
                if (checkPermission()) {

                    Snackbar.make(view, "Permission already granted.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {

                    Snackbar.make(view, "Please request permission.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.request_permission:
                if (!checkPermission()) {

                    requestPermission();

                } else {

                    Snackbar.make(view, "Permission already granted.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }
    }

    private void requestPermission() {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state allows you to earn on incoming calls. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Snackbar.make(view, "Permission Granted, Now you can access phone manager.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {

                    Snackbar.make(view, "Permission Denied, You cannot access phone manager.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the logs from log cat?

Comment: I solved it. I just placed the value in IncomingCall and Retreived it in MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

You could put the value to sharedpref in IncomingCall and retrieve in MainActivity.